# What could be preventing Google Chrome developer tools' audit from completing?

Tags: performance, google-chrome

I'm trying to run Chrome developer tools' audit on http://www.zmxmusic.com, and it never completes... just gets up to about "Loading (61 of 61)" with the spinner but never shows the results.

If I check the Network tab, there are no requests pending; all requests are complete and without errors.

Audit works fine on other sites.

**EDIT** Added actual site URL.

Comment: What is the address?

Comment: Please share the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using 16.0.912.63 beta-m on Windows 7 x64 and having the exact same problem with multiple sites.

I decided to check http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

The dev tools page suggests updating to latest developer build if you are a web developer.

Now I'm using Chrome Build 17.0.963.12 and the audit tool loads results.